# Jssor refreshing .gif

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, gif, jssor

I'm trying to load gif images into a jssor slider via code, but didn't work with my code and i don't know why.
The purpose is that each image refreshes when shown, cause the gif animation is not a loop, i have to do it this way.
Thanks in advance, here i put the code that is changing the images:

The variables wich will contain the images...

```
var imagen1 = new Image();
var imagen2 = new Image();
var imagen3 = new Image();
imagen1.src = "./1.gif";
imagen2.src = "./2.gif";
imagen3.src = "./3.gif";
```

And the code to change them...

```
function OnSlidePark(slideIndex, fromIndex) {
    switch (slideIndex) {
        case 0:
            $('#i1').attr('src', imagen1.src);
            break;
        case 1:
            $('#i2').attr('src', imagen2.src);
            break;
        case 2:
            $('#i3').attr('src', imagen3.src);
            break;
    }
}
```

By the way, the sources and the Id's are working correctly

Answer (score 0):

Will the following codes work?

```
function OnSlidePark(slideIndex, fromIndex) {
    switch (slideIndex) {
        case 0:
            $('#i1').attr('src', '');
            $('#i1').attr('src', imagen1.src);
            break;
        case 1:
            $('#i2').attr('src', '');
            $('#i2').attr('src', imagen2.src);
            break;
        case 2:
            $('#i3').attr('src', '');
            $('#i3').attr('src', imagen3.src);
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nope, it's the same. I tried to do the same without the slider and it works, so i think that must be a property or something required in jssor to do this change of images, but i don't know how

Comment: Does the gif image show? Or it would not rewind the gif animation to the beginning when the src is reset?

Comment: If i put the src in the html it's shown correctly, but leaving the src without path makes the slider show only the alt attribute at each image, but i cannot reset the images in that two cases

Comment: Please check the image element by 'inspect element' to see if the src is assigned correctly.

Comment: Also, please try your code to assign the src to any image element which is not in slider.

Comment: inspect element show that the images has the src of the html code, not the one given by that js code. Seems that i cannot change the image this way, there is something in jssor that allows changes in the src of the slider images? PD:I tried that code in gif's images out of the slider, and it's working

Comment: I'm using the debug console now, and each time i scroll the slider it gives me this error:  net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND   jssor.js:1795